# Can a business owner refuse specific Bills and Coins?

Tags: canada, business, currency, legal-tender

I was reading an article [article](https://torontosun.com/news/national/pizza-place-owner-refuses-john-a-macdonald-10-bills) which outlines a Pizza Shop owner in Canada who is refusing to take $10 Bills with John A. MacDonald on them. For context John A. MacDonald(the first Prime Minister of Canada) was on all $10 bills until 2017, when the new series had the obverse replaced by Viola Desmond, of bills currently in circulation I would say roughly half are of the old variety, just based on my experience.

Forgetting all nuances and subtleties of current events and why this man made his decision; is this allowed? The bills are recognized as Canadian Currency, and as a business operating in Canada is there not an obligation to serve all Canadians fairly regardless of the person on the face of their currency, since they definitely did not make that choice themselves?

Of course many places do not accept $100 bills, but that is because of forgery. It seems to be that being able to deny someone business based on when their money was printed is awfully shakey ground, what if something terrible happened to me in 2020 and I refuse all coins minted that year?

Comment: The shop owner may argue that he only accepts bills newer than 2018 because there are a lot of old fake notes around. This is the same argument as for $100 bills.

Comment: The shop owner would have to notify you that those notes are not accepted before you place your order otherwise they are wasting pizza.

Answer (score 19):

Canada may have specific different laws, but in most countries any legal tender must be accepted for payment of a debt. There are subtleties; in the UK for example more than 20 one penny coins are not legal tender. Old coins or banknotes may cease to be legal tender at some point and can only be exchanged at a bank; it seems Canada's $10 bill is nowhere near that point.

The biggest "loophole" is that a business owner doesn't have to allow you to create a debt. Say you go shopping in a supermarket for $40. You take your shopping, you now have a $40 debt. You take four $10 bills and hand them over, your debt is paid. At that point this $10 bill must be accepted. However, the shop owner could refuse to let you take the shopping if he doesn't like your bills. So you have no debt, so he doesn't have to accept legal tender as a debt.

In a restaurant, where you typically eat your food, creating a debt, then he cannot refuse the $10 bill. And in a shop, this will not be good for his business. If my $10 bills are not accepted, then I will take advantage of my right to shop elsewhere.

Comment: In the UK, it's even worse than that. From the [Bank of England website](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/knowledgebank/what-is-legal-tender): "English banknotes aren’t legal tender in Scotland. Scottish notes aren’t legal tender in England or Scotland. Debit cards, cheques and contactless aren’t legal tender anywhere."

Comment: I had a cab driver in Scotland "pretend" to not know what an English 5-pound note was. I think he saw the Bank of Scotland one as I pulled the money out of my pocket. He probably would have taken the English one, but he saw he had a choice (and I was thankfully partially aware of the distinction). The English money was given to me by the Bank of Scotland. The Scottish notes were given as change for English ones.

Comment: Also, be careful with what is implied by "legal tender", which means it has to be accepted in settlement of a debt. If the shopkeeper has big signs saying "this money doesn't spend here", he may be effectively adding a condition to his contract with the customer, in which case, there's no debt to be settled and "legal tender" becomes irrelevant. IANAL

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff "Republic credits are no good here"

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff You are quoting selectively. Further down the page, that site says (correctly) "Legal tender has a narrow technical meaning which has no use in everyday life. "

Comment: The supermarket example would be dubious in the US. In a retail store, the act of "shopping" does not oblige payment, i.e. create debt. When you pay for items before leaving a store it amounts to a legal exchange of property ownership between you and the store with transaction settlement at the point of sale. Likewise, failure to pay before leaving a store's premises is not debt default but rather simple property theft.  A restaurant is different since served food is not considered property but service fulfillment, and ordering of service is an express agreement subject to debt obligation.

Comment: What about damaged bills? Businesses and individuals are allowed to refuse currency that's damaged or altered (cut, torn, worn down, permanently discolored, etc....), atleast in the United States.

Comment: try spending at £50 in ANY corner shop in the UK, and then re-write your answer lol

Comment: @PeterH what aspect of the answer do you think needs rewriting? It specifically says "the shop owner could refuse to let you take the shopping if he doesn't like your bills". What's different about the corner shop and the £50?

Comment: @JamesMartin this was written in jest and my annoyance at not being able to spend legal tender (£50 note) anywhere in the UK, wasn't a dig at the answer that's why I put a lol at the end of my comment

Comment: Is there any reference describing shoppers as taking on debt that's then settled at the counter?  My impression was that shoppers performed transactions where the items become theirs as the payment is accepted.

Comment: More more than 20 pennies?  But, but, ... how about _halfpennies_?  I seem to remember John Steed was proud of being a halfpenny millionaire, which he stored neatly in conveniently sized boxes ... but was he limited to spending it only 20 coins at a time??

Comment: @davidbak The 20-coin limit isn't a hard maximum, just a point beyond which the recipient is allowed to refuse.  Not everyone will necessarily refuse to accept a box of halfpennies as payment.

Comment: In the UK "Legal tender" has a far more specific and narrow meaning than most people realise.  All it means is that if you offer 'legal tender' to settle a debt that the creditor cannot sue you for failing to pay.  Only up to 20p in 'copper' (1p/2p coins) count, and shop owners have no obligation to accept cash or give change since purchasing in a store is not payment of a debt - it's a swap, buyer's cash for seller's goods so if they don't like your money they can decide not to complete the transaction.  https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/knowledgebank/what-is-legal-tender

Answer (score 5):

CBC, the public Canadian broadcaster, [quotes the Bank of Canada](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/it-may-be-legal-tender-but-more-businesses-are-snubbing-cash-1.4428655):

> Even though it is legal currency, the Bank of Canada says it is not mandatory for
> Canadian businesses to accept cash.
>
> According to the Bank of Canada, retailers don't have to take bills or coins "because
> **both parties must agree on the payment method."**

I find that surprising because it undermines the value of legal tender. There is, of course, a principle conflict between freedom of contract on one hand and the interest of societies (via their governments) to maintain the value and usability of their domestic currency on the other hand. Canada resolved it favoring freedom of contract. In the European Union the conflict is still not uniformly decided (see [Report of the Euro Legal Tender Expert Group (ELTEG), undated, p. 6)](https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/articles/euro/documents/elteg_en.pdf). The recommendation of that paper is about the opposite of the Canadian regulation: A business must accept cash *unless* both parties agree to use a different form of payment.

Comment: The value of "legal tender" is to set a uniform standard for satisfying existing financial obligations, not to force parties into contracts they don't want to agree to.

Comment: @Sneftel A host of laws "force parties into contracts they don't want to agree to", especially the business in business to customer relationships.

Comment: Exactly. And they do so *very carefully*, in order to balance individual rights against the public interest. The importance of legal tender is to establish an official currency in a state, not to force a gas station to take your $100 bill or your sack of pennies.

Comment: @Sneftel The obvious issue is that the $100 bill is only good to wipe my behind if nobody accepts it. Paper money's value is pure faith, and sometimes a little threat helps the faith ;-).

Comment: That's where the invisible hand of the market comes in. Someone with a $100 credit card debt will gladly buy your $100 bill for 50 $1 bills, since they'll come out $50 ahead on the deal. But then someone else would give you 60 $1 bills to compete, etc. As long as there's debts, there's a market. Friction in the details of monetary exchange is a matter of market realities, and not something the state usually has a compelling interest in interfering with (but see various jurisdictions that *have* banned "credit card only" retail, to avoid marginalizing people without a bank account).

Comment: @Sneftel "force... to take your $100" that's exactly what it's for in the US, although at a gas station, you haven't generally incurred a debt prior to paying, so the point is moot.  Where this is important is, say, the title loan you took out on your car for $500.  Suppose they refuse your cash.  What then?  They insist that you pay them back in golden Spanish doubloons, or they'll take your car.  Well, they can't, because anyone that *you already owe a debt to* must allow you to settle that debt in a reasonable way, and that reasonable way is with US$.

Comment: @Him Yes, I know. That’s what I was describing. (A title loan is an example of a “financial obligation”.)

Answer (score 3):

The [Canadian Human Rights Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/h-6/FullText.html) states

> 5 It is a discriminatory practice in the provision of goods, services,
> facilities or accommodation customarily available to the general
> public
>
> (a) to deny, or to deny access to, any such good, service,
> facility or accommodation to any individual, or
>
> (b) to differentiate adversely in relation to any individual,
>
> on a prohibited ground of discrimination.

And the "prohibited ground of discrimination" is your usual fare of sex, race, national origin, ex-cons, or pregnant women. Can't refuse service to any person for those reasons.

But after searching Canadian laws for other reasons someone may refuse service, I couldn't find any. At the end of the day, the shop keeper owns the merchandise, and as such he and he alone determines the conditions under which it leaves his possession. If he doesn't like your money, then he doesn't have to accept it. Legal tender in Canada is simply regarded as notes printed by the Bank of Canada, and ['In legal terms, it means “the money approved in a country for paying debts.”'](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/about-legal-tender/), but contains no obligation in its definition to be accepted by Canadian citizens if a debt isn't owed.

Comment: The Canadian Human Rights Act doesn't apply in any case, it is a federal act that cannot apply to restaurants etc. under exclusive provincial jurisdiction (even if on First Nations land). But I would assume Nova Scotia's equivalent is similar and doesn't prohibit this specifically either.

Comment: The scenario in the question isn't about refusing service, it's about refusing a particular form of payment.

Comment: Which may result in denying the sale, thus service.